# A Muirhead Like Inequality

Tags: inequalities, symmetric-functions, majorization

> I am looking for a proof of the inequality as follow:

Let $n$ be an integer number $n \ge 2$ and $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ and $y_1,\cdots, y_n$ are nonegative real numbers such that $(x_1,\cdots, x_n)$ [majorizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) $(y_1,\cdots, y_n)$; Let $0 \leq a_1, a_2,\cdots,a_n \leq 1$ then

$$\sum_{\text{sym}} {x_1}^{a_1}{x_2}^{a_2}\cdots {x_n}^{a_n}\leq \sum_{\text{sym}} {y_1}^{a_1}{y_2}^{a_2}\cdots {y_n}^{a_n}$$

Note: The inequality above is not [Muirhead's Inequality](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/MuirheadInequality.shtml).

**Example:** Let $0 \leq a_i \leq 1$ then

- $4^{a_1}1^{a_2}+ 4^{a_2}1^{a_1} \le 3^{a_1}2^{a_2}+ 3^{a_2}2^{a_1}$
- $5^{a_1}5^{a_2}2^{a_3}+5^{a_1}5^{a_3}2^{a_2}+5^{a_2}5^{a_1}2^{a_3}+5^{a_2}5^{a_3}2^{a_1}+5^{a_3}5^{a_1}2^{a_2}+5^{a_3}5^{a_2}2^{a_1}
  \leq 4.5^{a_1}4^{a_2}3.5^{a_3}+4.5^{a_1}4^{a_3}3.5^{a_2}+4.5^{a_2}4^{a_1}3.5^{a_3}+4.5^{a_2}4^{a_3}3.5^{a_1}+4.5^{a_3}4^{a_1}3.5^{a_2}+4.5^{a_3}4^{a_2}3.5^{a_1}$

**See also:**

- [Muirhead's Inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Muirhead%27s_Inequality)
- [Group multiplication of permutations](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/PermGroup.shtml)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\be}{\beta}
\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}
\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}
\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}
\newcommand{\thh}{\theta}
\newcommand{\om}{\omega}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathsf E}} 
\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{\mathsf Var}} 
\renewcommand{\P}{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}
\newcommand{\ii}[1]{\operatorname{\mathsf I}\{#1\}} 
\newcommand{\tf}{\widetilde{f}} 
\newcommand{\tsi}{\tilde\si}$

For $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in(0,\infty)$, let 
\begin{equation*}
 f(x):=2\sum_{\si\in S_n}\prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{a_{\si(k)}}, 
\end{equation*}
where $S_n$ is the set of all permutations of the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$. By the symmetry and the [Schur--Ostrowski criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur-convex_function), it suffices to show that 
\begin{equation*}
x_1\le x_2\overset{\text{(?)}}\implies f_1(x)-f_2(x)\ge0, \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where $f_j(x)$ is the partial derivative of $f(x)$ in $x_j$. 
Consider the bijection $S_n\ni\si\leftrightarrow\tsi\in S_n$ defined by the formula 
\begin{equation*}
 \tsi(k):=
 \left\{
 \begin{aligned}
 \si(2)&\text{ if }k=1,\\
 \si(1)&\text{ if }k=2,\\
 \si(k)&\text { otherwise}. 
 \end{aligned}
 \right.
\end{equation*}
Then 
\begin{align*}
 f(x)&:=\sum_{\si\in S_n}x_1^{a_{\si(1)}}x_2^{a_{\si(2)}}\prod_{k=3}^n x_k^{a_{\si(k)}}
 + \sum_{\tsi\in S_n}x_1^{a_{\tsi(1)}}x_2^{a_{\tsi(2)}}\prod_{k=3}^n x_k^{a_{\tsi(k)}}  
 =\sum_{\si\in S_n}Q P, \tag{2}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{equation*}
 Q:=Q_\si(x):=x_1^{b_1}x_2^{b_2}+x_1^{b_2}x_2^{b_1},\quad P:=P_\si(x):=\prod_{k=3}^n x_k^{b_k},  
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 b_k:=b_{\si;k}:=a_{\si(k)}. 
\end{equation*}
Denoting by $Q_j$ the partial derivative of $Q$ in $x_j$, we have 
\begin{equation*}
 Q_1-Q_2=b_1 (x_1 x_2)^{b_1-1}(x_2^{b_2-b_1+1}-x_1^{b_2-b_1+1})
 +b_2 (x_1 x_2)^{b_2-1}(x_2^{b_1-b_2+1}-x_1^{b_1-b_2+1})\ge0. 
\end{equation*}
Now noting that $P$ does not depend on $(x_1,x_2)$, we see that (1) follows from (2), as desired.

Comment: @ĐàoThanhOai: the first name of  Iosif start with "I" not "L". see the last sentence of [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300731/why-the-autoregressive-process-to-generate-random-time-series/300739#comment748764_300739) of Iosif.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry; Thank You very much dear @Mahdi and IosifPinelis